# Understanding how Perl fork works

Tags: perl, fork

What would be the right way to fork processes that each one of them runs a different subroutine `sub1,sub2,...,subN`. After reading a lot of previous thread and material, I feel that I understand the logic but a bit confused on how to write in the cleanest way possible (readability is important to me).

Consider 4 subs. Each one of them gets different arguments. It feels like that the most efficient way would be to create 7 forks that each one of them will run a different sub. The code will look something like this:

```
my $forks = 0;
foreach my $i (1..4) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        my $pid = fork();
        if ($pid == 0) {
            $forks++;
            run1();
            exit;
        }
    } elsif ($i == 2) {
        my $pid = fork();
        if ($pid == 0) {
            $forks++;
            run1();
            exit;
        }
    } elsif ($i == 3) {
        my $pid = fork();
        if ($pid == 0) {
            $forks++;
            run1();
            exit;
        }
    } elsif ($i == 4) {
        my $pid = fork();
        if ($pid == 0) {
            $forks++;
            run1();
            exit;
        }
    }

}

for (1 .. $forks) {
    my $pid = wait();
    print "Parent saw $pid exiting\n";
}
print "done\n";
```

Some points:

- This will work only if all of the forks were successful. But I would like to run the subs even though the fork failed (even though it will not be parallel. In that case, I guess we need to take the subs out of the if and exit only if the $pid wasn't `0`. something like:

  ```
  my $pid = fork();
  run1();
  $forks++ if ($pid == 0);
  exit if ($pid == 0);
  ```

  But it still feels not right.
- Using `exit` is the right way to kill the child process? if the processes were killed with `exit` should I still use `wait`? Will it prevent zombies?
- Maybe the most interesting question: What will I do if we have 15 function calls? I would like to somehow create 15 forks but I can't create 15 if-else statements - the code will not be readable that way. At first, I thought that it is possible to insert those function calls into an array (somehow) and loop over that array. But after some research, I didn't find a way that it is possible.
- If possible, I prefer not to use any additional modules like `Parallel::ForkManager`.

Is there a clean and simple way to solve it?

Comment: `$forks` will not be incremented in the parent process, because you only increment it in the child processes. Your code only ever calls `run1()` Where do you call `sub1` .. `subN`?

Comment: `wait()` is what prevents zombies, not `exit`. You must call `wait()` N times before calling exiting the main process if you had N successful forks.

Comment: How about `if ($pid < 1) { /* child or failed */ sub1(); /* child */ exit() if $pid == 0; } else ( /* parent */ $forks++; }`? But while `subX` is executing for a failed fork, you will have zombies, because you are only calling `wait()` after everything is done.

Comment: Crossposted at https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1228560

Comment: Re "*This will work only if ...*", Actually, it doesn;t work. `$forks` is always `0` in the parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few questions to clear up here.

A basic example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @coderefs;    
for my $i (1..4) { 
    push @coderefs, sub { 
        my @args = @_; 
        say "Sub #$i with args: @args";
    };
}

my @procs;
for my $i (0 .. $#coderefs) {
    my $pid = fork  // do {
        warn "Can't fork: $!";
        # retry, or record which subs failed so to run later
        next;
    };  
    if ($pid == 0) { 
        $coderefs[$i]->("In $$: $i");
        exit;
    }   
    push @procs, $pid;
    #sleep 1;
}    
say "Started: @procs";

for my $pid (@procs) {
    my $goner = waitpid $pid, 0;
    say "$goner exited with $?";
}
```

We generate anonymous subroutines and store those code references in an array, then go through that array and start that many processes, running a sub in each. After that the parent `waitpid`s on these in the order in which they were started, but normally you'll want to reap as they exit; see docs listed below.

A child process always `exit`s, or you'd have multiple processes executing all of the rest of the code in the program.  Once a child process exits the kernel will notify the parent, and the parent can "pick up" that notification ("reap" the exit status of the child process) via `wait`/`waitpid`, or use a signal handler to handle/ignore it.

If the parent never does this after the child exited, once it exits itself later the OS stays stuck with that information about the (exited) child process in the process table; that's a zombie. So you do need to `wait`, so that OS gets done with the child process (and you check up on how it went). Or, you can indicate in a signal handler that you don't care about the child's exit.<sup>†</sup>  Modern systems reap would-be zombies but not always and you cannot rely on that; clean up after yourself.

Note, you'll need to be reading [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), [fork](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html), [wait](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) and [waitpid](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html), [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) ... and yet other resources that'll come up while working on all this. It will take a little playing and some trial and error.  Once you get it all down you may want to start using modules, at least for some types of tasks.

---

<sup>†</sup> To ignore the SIGCHLD (default)

```
$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
```

Or, can run code there (but well advised to be minimal)

```
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { ... };
```

These signal "dispositions" are inherited in fork-ed processes (but not via `execve`).

See the docs listed above, and the basics of `%SIG` variable [in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25SIG).  Also see `man(7) signal`.  All this is generally *nix business.

This is a global variable, affecting all code in the interpreter. In order to limit the change to the nearest scope use [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29)

```
local $SIG{CHLD} = ...
```

Comment: The other benefit of wait and waitpid is that after it has reaped a process, `$?` will tell you the exit status.

Comment: @Grinnz Right, and while it's in the text and code I should've stated it right up front, the first time it's mentioned. Edited, thanks